# Unknown changes that require Repository Update

Tags: c#, repository, domain-driven-design

I have an `Employee` entity with the method `Authenticate(SecureString password)` during this method the `LastAuthenticatedDate` private member is altered with the expectation it will be persisted.

though that makes it very awkward for the "calling layers" as they are now required to do the following (without fail, else the data will not be correct):

```
if (myEmployee.Authenticate(password))
{
    // do stuff
    employeeRepository.Update(myEmployee); // so that the last authentication date is persisted.
}
```

This is very awkward and I can see this pattern cropping up everywhere in my domain model, my expectation is that it should be saved automatically to the persistence store, however without somehow injecting a repository (or service?) I don't see how that is possible.

The domain model is persistence ignorant, but an `IAuthenticationService` could be injected and through double-dispatch could update the repository for me. Is that the correct approach in terms of DDD?

**Update**
The following snippet may be useful in getting a better picture of what I'm doing.

```
public bool Authenticate(SecureString password)
{
    bool isSuccess = false;
    var hash = new HashedPassword(password, Password.Salt);

    if (Password.Validate(hash))
    {
        _lastLogin = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        isSuccess = true;
    }

    DomainEvents.RaiseEvent(new EmployeeAuthenticationEvent(this, isSuccess));
    return isSuccess;
}
```

Comment: How are your repositories scoped? If you scope them at, say, request-level for a web app, then on dispose they can persist any changes to your domain models. Thus, the repository being disposed is your automatic `Update` call.

Comment: That's a good idea! I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "how are your repositories scoped?" though, could you clarify?

Comment: Though it would require that I keep an in memory list of references to the fetched entities and impose similar expected behaviour on all other implementations of `IXxxxRepository` not to mention if the list is large running through it and updating every entity could hurt performance... my current implementation is an abstraction over Entity Framework where I map the persistence models to domain models in the repository (another difficult problem to solve effectively in DDD)

Comment: EF tracks the objects like NHibernate doesn't it? Our/my setup is to let NHibernate track the references and a simple `Commit` at the end of the request (via Ninject `InRequestScope`) persists everything. DDD is particularly bad for this setup yes.. which is why I try and event source with DDD (since impedance mismatch can be a bit of a killer with DDD).

Comment: EF Tracks its own entities but in my implementation the EF entities are used only to transfer data read from the database to my domain models via the static method SomeEntity.Restore(various parameters) which is called in the repository methods. Keeping a separate set of domain entities over EF is proving to be more trouble than its worth.. almost..

Comment: You should still be able to pass your higher level objects back down and apply them over the EF ones. We do this: [UpdatedModel] -> [Service] -> [ServiceGetEFObject] -> [AutoMapper apply viewmodel changes to EF model object] -> EF commits at end of request. So, you re-load the EF objects .. update them with the new values.. and EF commits the tracked changes after that.

Comment: That is how I'm doing it pretty much, except I call `Update` on my repository which maps my domain model back to an EF model sets the modified state and eventually a call to SaveChanges is made.. The issue here is its not immediately obvious anyone should call Update/Commit after certain operations such as Authenticate, potential for bugs and violates the DRY principle.  Any internal changes should be persisted as soon as possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52480/discussion-between-simon-whitehead-and-reegan-layzell)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't Inject a Repository or Service layer into your Domain Model if that's what you're asking.

I would place the piece of code you're talking about in a Domain Service Layer.

```
class EmployeeAuthenticationService implements AuthenticationService {
    public void authenticate(Employee employee, String password) {
        if (employee.Authenticate(password)) {
            // do stuff
            employeeRepository.Update(myEmployee);   
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: This is a slippery slope towards an *Anemic Domain Model* providing a service with such an implementation warrants the question why should I even have an `Authenticate` method on the employee, and instead just put all the code in the service? Also, IMO, having two interfaces that suggest they perform the same operation yet their implementations differ in expected behaviour is bad.

Comment: However, I would argue that in this case a service *should* be used to authenticate an employee, per what I know to be good OO practice, why should an Employee know how to Authenticate itself?

Comment: Indeed I must agree that an employee should not know how to authenticate itself. If you change the code so that the above service uses properties of the employee object to authenticate (using an Application Service I think) it moves away from leaning towards an Anemic Domain Model.

Comment: I'm still thinking about this... It has been suggested to me to use the domain event raised by the `Authenticate` (see update in OP) method to persist the internal state changes of invariants (in this case the last login date).  Using a domain service would mean exposing some way of setting the _lastLogin field which isn't satisfactory, this particular invariant (and many like it) should be entirely encapsulated only available for reading publicly... Perhaps the backwards looking `employee.Authenticate(password, authenticationService)` ?

Comment: Trouble with that route though is it isn't clear what the layers above should be using to authenticate at first.  Do they use the straight `Authenticate(Employee, SecureString)` interface method or go through the employee?